# How to know from what table record is retrieved in Sphinx?

Tags: sphinx

from sphinx.conf:

```
source src0 {
    type = pgsql
    sql_host = localhost
    sql_user = <db user>
    sql_pass = <pwd>
    sql_db = <db name>
    sql_port = 5432
    sql_query = \
        SELECT id, header, text, "app_main" as table_name \
        FROM app_main
    sql_query_info = SELECT * FROM app_main WHERE id=$id
    sql_attr_string = table_name
}

source src1 {
    type = pgsql
    sql_host = localhost
    sql_user = <db user>
    sql_pass = <pwd>
    sql_db = <db name>
    sql_port = 5432
    sql_query = \
        SELECT id, header, text, "app_product" as table_name \
        FROM app_product
    sql_query_info = SELECT * FROM app_product WHERE id=$id
    sql_attr_string = table_name
}

index global_index {
    source = src0
    source = src1
    path = D:/blizzard/Projects/Python/Web/moz455/app/sphinx/data/global_index
    docinfo = extern
    charset_type = utf-8
}
```

Command

```
client.Query(S, '*')
```

returns

```
{'status': 0, 'matches': [{'id': 5, 'weight': 30, 'attrs': {}}], 'fields': ['header', 'text'], 'time': '0.000', 'total_found': 1, 'warning': '', 'attrs': [], 'words': [{'docs': 1, 'hits': 2, 'word': 'styless'}], 'error': '', 'total': 1})
```

Why attrs dict is empty? Is this the right way to get table name and if not - what is?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you rebuild the index after changing the the config file

Best to restart sphinx after changing config

Specify the actual index name(s) in the query, rather than just using '*' - all indexes should have the required attribute(s)